# How to setup Wi-Fi Direct with PIN on Android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I want to require entering a PIN when connecting two Android devices to ensure they are talking to each other.

There is a sample project in the Android SDK 17 called "WiFiDirectDemo". It establishes a Wi-Fi Direct connection but it lacks the PIN authentication.

1. I don't know how to specify WiFiP2pConfig.wps.setup in the class DeviceDetailFragment around line 71. Do I specify the action on the current device (I want to show a auto-generated four-digit PIN), i. e. config.wps.setup = WPSInfo.DISPLAY, or should I specify the action on the peer, i. e. config.wps.setup = WPSInfo.KEYPAD?
2. How can I detect the connection request on the other peer? I guess there is something I can listen to, e. g. in the BroadcastReceiver, but I cannot find it.

I'm an experienced iOS developer but Android is very new to me, maybe the the answer is obvious to you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the action on the device which sends the connect request ... and for  pin i think this should work

p2pconfig.wps.setup = WpsInfo.DISPLAY;
p2pconfig.wps.pin = "0000";
On connect, PIN is displayed on local device and requests user to enter same PIN on remote device; once PIN is entered, connect completes successfully.

Check this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/hN5WfXRzXpI read the 5th post

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried adding those two lines to the demo app but it still connects without prompting/showing a dialog. As I understand from your explanation and the linked forum entry there is nothing else to do.

Comment: I found the problem. Apparently it is enough to pair the devices once (in my case implicitly). There is only question left: How do I remove a pairing? If you know it fine, otherwise I'll dig through the docs. :)

Comment: if you want to remove a group i think there is a function in wifip2pmanager called remove group which takes as argument the channel in which communication is taking place , so if you call this function from the Group owner device providing the correct channel the group should be terminated

Comment: You can also manually remove the groups by going to wifi settings, hitting the menu and selecting "Wifi Direct". From there you'll see a list of all remembered groups with the option to forget any group.

Answer (score 1):

p2pconfig.wps.setup=WpsInfo.KEYPAD(don't specify p2pconfig.wps.pin) works fine for me.It displays a dynamically generated key on the device from which we are trying to connect to be entered on the other device.

In this case you don't need to listen on any b'cast receiver to detect the connection.The wpa_supplicant takes care of it and prompts you to enter the pin.For a clear picture, look at the logcat(I use adb from ADT(sdk+eclipse) to see the logcat) of wpa_supplicant while connection is in progress.